# Making an app with xcode with a map showing a route

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, routes

Hello
I need to make an app that shows you your current position on a defined route. As I am new to xCode, I'm just playing around a little bit. I am organizing a walk with an already chosen route. And I want my app to show this route on a map, with the current position of the walker, so that they can see how far it is to the finish line. A little display showing your already walked distance and the distance to go would be nice to.
Could you please give me some tips?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You should consider refining your question to make it clear exactly what kind of tips you are after. Have you programmed before? Do you want a tutorial on GPS orientated applications?

Comment: Following may help you: http://code.google.com/p/octomapkit/ https://github.com/route-me/route-me/archives/master

Comment: Well, a tutorial would be nice, but the problem is, I have never done anything like that before, I just got the basics in C, so...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you've picked a difficult challenge for your first Xcode outing. Navigation is fine, but showing routes has been made deliberately hard because Google don't want everyone doing that with their maps.

Have a look at the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).